# Filtering based on previous filter

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Using this code I have set up I am using Filters which work in correlation with userforms with checkboxes to choose what to filter. Currently if I filter on one variable like Utilities it Filters, but if I move to another filter say Clients and then I filter instead of giving me the clients associated with the specific utility previously filtered it clears everything and filters only on the clients.

I am thinking the solution may have to deal with the Method:
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

```
Private Sub Cancel_UF_Click()
    UtilityFilter.Hide
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub

Private Sub Confirm_UF_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("UMC626")
    ClearFilter
    UpdateFilters
    UtilityFilter.Hide
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="UMC626", _
                        DrawingObjects:=False, _
                        Contents:=True, _
                        Scenarios:=True
End Sub

Sub SelectAll_UF_Click()
    If SelectAll = True Then
        Electricty_UF.Value = True
        Gas_UF.Value = True
        NonUtility_UF.Value = True
        SolarElectricity_UF.Value = True
        SolarThermal_UF.Value = True
        SolidWaste_UF.Value = True
        Water_UF.Value = True
    Else
        Electricity_UF.Value = False
        Gas_UF.Value = False
        NonUtility_UF.Value = False
        SolarElectricity_UF.Value = False
        SolarThermal_UF.Value = False
        SolidWaste_UF.Value = False
        Water_UF.Value = False
    End If
End Sub

Sub UpdateFilters()
    Integer_UF = -1

    If Electricity_UF.Value = True Then
        Add_UF String_UF, "E"
        Range("E6:E67").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                                   Criteria1:=String_UF, _
                                   Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If

    If Gas_UF.Value = True Then
        Add_UF String_UF, "G"
        Range("E6:E67").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                                   Criteria1:=String_UF, _
                                   Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If

    If NonUtility_UF.Value = True Then
        Add_UF String_UF, "NU"
        Range("E6:E67").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                                   Criteria1:=String_UF, _
                                   Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If

    If SolarElectricity_UF.Value = True Then
        Add_UF String_UF, "SE"
        Range("E6:E67").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                                   Criteria1:=String_UF, _
                                   Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If

    If SolarElectricity_UF.Value = True Then
        Add_UF String_UF, "SE"
        Range("E6:E67").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                                   Criteria1:=String_UF, _
                                   Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If

    If SolarThermal_UF.Value = True Then
        Add_UF String_UF, "ST"
        Range("E6:E67").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                                   Criteria1:=String_UF, _
                                   Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If

    If SolidWaste_UF.Value = True Then
        Add_UF String_UF, "SW"
        Range("E6:E67").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                                   Criteria1:=String_UF, _
                                   Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If

    If Water_UF.Value = True Then
        Add_UF String_UF, "W"
        Range("E6:E67").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                                   Criteria1:=String_UF, _
                                   Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If
End Sub

Sub Add_UF(String_UF() As String, NewValue As String)
    Integer_UF = Integer_UF + 1
    ReDim Preserve String_UF(Integer_UF)
    String_UF(Integer_UF) = NewValue
End Sub
```

I think the focus should be on Add_UF
I am calling a NewValue. Is there anyway to sort a column after it has been sorted? As you can see in the picture below I'd like to beable to sort one colum. Say on Energy then after that sort it on Work Type. [image]

Comment: You have a lot of code there. You are more likely to get a response if you ask a more specific question and identify what line(s) of your code are most relevant to your question.

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not intend to re-write your code but I can provide the information, and methods, that you will need to achieve what you want.

Currently you are focusing on a single column:

```
Range("E6:E67").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
```

You should extend this to the whole table area:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$M$112").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Leeds"
```

The number 6 is the sixth column within the filter range. You might also create a Range reference to refer to the filter-range:

```
Dim rngFilter As Range
Set rngFilter = Worksheets("Staff List").AutoFilter.Range
```

The filters accumulate, so the following will filter on two columns:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$M$112").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Leeds"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$M$112").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Sales"
```

At some point you will Clear the filters:

```
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

Clearing a single filter is just applying a filter with no criteria:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$M$112").AutoFilter Field:=7
```

If you record a macro to **Sort** on more than one column (using Custom Sort) it creates code like the following, to which I've added some comments:

```
'clear the previous Sort
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staff List").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear

'accumulate the SortFields
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staff List").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("C6:C112"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staff List").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("B6:B112"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal

'Apply the Sort
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Staff List").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .Apply
End With
```

Recording Macros will also reveal other methods and properties that may be useful to you. The recorded code will not be elegant, and can be reduced (tidied) significantly, but it does provide useful information.

Comment: Knowing to extend it to the entire table was vis probably going to do it. Thanks